# a volcanic literature of the body as well as the heart

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "volcanic literature of the body" mean in the text below?
Is the writer saying Charlotte Bronte devoted a great deal of her writings to describing body and sensations?

> In rejecting Austen and deciding instead to write about "what throbs fast and full, though hidden, what the blood rushes through, what is the unseen seat of life," Charlotte Bronte had chosen a **volcanic literature of the body** as well as of the heart, a sexual and often supernatural world. She was thus seen as the romantic, the spontaneous artist who "pours forth her feelings . . . without premeditation." George Eliot was seen as the opposite: a writer and a woman in the Austen tradition, studied, intellectual, cultivated.
>
> — Showalter, Elaine. "The Double Critical Standard and the Feminine Novel," in *A Literature of Their Own: British Women Novelists From Brontë to Lessing,* pp. 73-99. Princeton, N. J.: Princeton University Press, 1977, via [encyclopedia.com](https://www.encyclopedia.com/social-sciences/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/womens-literature-19th-century-british-women-writers)

Comment: "Volcanic literature of" means nothing at all. Ask about "volcanic literature" or "volcanic literature of the body". Otherwise it's "of what"? Also, formatting is important, and correct citation is mandatory.

Comment: Once I used the same format as yours for citation, but someone changed it to "source" format. I'm not sure which version do I have to stick to.

Comment: A single "Source" link is not acceptable, so you were right. See [Help on referencing](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Using the full text allows the source to be instantly seen without clicking the link; and if the post should be extracted without the link (as does happen with re-use of content), then it's not reproduced with the single word "Source" leaving no idea of where it came from originally. [Here, we can see that the quote is from a 1977 essay and might even form an opinion about its viewpoint, all without clicking the link.]

Comment: That's true. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

*Volcanic literature" is a  simple analogy between two things: geological volcanism; and life as depicted by Bronte. Volcanic systems are often quiet and smoulder gently for long periods, underlain by latent subterranean motions, punctuated by dramatic eruptions of destructive violence or irresistible force. The literary creations of Bronte similarly are based on normally lived life, which is underlain by undercurrents of sex, greed, jealousy and other emotions; these occasionally break out with destructive consequence or irresistible force, as in the tale she tells.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I understand it.